# Infinite Rotation Command (or button) in toolbar in Codename One

Tags: java, toolbar, codenameone, infinite

I'd like to 'infinite' rotate on of my Commands (the refresh Command) in the [Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) [Toolbar](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Toolbar.html) (until loading is done, then I want to stop rotation, but the image still has to be visible). Can I change the icon so it will start rotation? How can I achieve this result?

The rotating icon should not be clickable when rotating, but that should not be that hard to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Toolbar API and a little bit of hack. I created the methods below to do that:

```
private void showTitleProgress(Toolbar t) {
    int pos = t.getComponentCount() - 1; //If you have a command on the left like back command
    //int pos = t.getComponentCount(); //If you don't have a command on the left like back command
    InfiniteProgress ip = new InfiniteProgress();
    ip.setAnimation(YourProgressImage);
    ip.setUIID("icon");
    Container contIp = FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(ip);

    Component.setSameWidth(t.getComponentAt(pos), contIp);
    Component.setSameHeight(t.getComponentAt(pos), contIp);
    t.replaceAndWait(t.getComponentAt(pos), contIp, null);
    t.revalidate();
}

private void hideTitleProgress(Toolbar t, Command cmd) {
    int pos = t.getComponentCount() - 1; //If you have a command on the left like back command
    //int pos = t.getComponentCount(); //If you don't have a command on the left like back command
    Button cmdButton = new Button(cmd.getIcon());
    cmdButton.setUIID("TitleCommand");
    cmdButton.setCommand(cmd);
    t.replaceAndWait(t.getComponentAt(pos), cmdButton, null);
    t.getComponentForm().revalidate();
}
```

Use it with Toolbar API and your form like this:

```
private Command myCommand = new Command("");
Form f = new Form("Test form");
Toolbar t = new Toolbar();
f.setToolbar(t);

Command back = new Command("Back") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
       //Do stuff
    }
};
back.putClientProperty("uiid", "BackCommand");
f.setBackCommand(back);
t.addCommandToLeftBar(back);

myCommand = new Command(YourProgressImage) {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //To show the progress when some actions are being performed 
        showTitleProgress(t);
        //When you're done, discard the progress and restore your command
        hideTitleProgress(t, myCommand);
    }
}
myCommand.putClientProperty("TitleCommand", true);
t.addCommandToRightBar(myCommand);
f.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! However, the commands are in a container next to the title (I have 2 commands), so I first fetch the container and then the commands in it. But thank you for your help!

Comment: I am wondering why the infinite progress image is smaller than the original image. I am using fontimage for the image. Maybe padding somewhere? I am going to find out. Other than that, it works ok now.